# C++ return local object

Tags: c++

Several co-workers and I are having a debate about what happens when a local variable (allocated on the stack) is returned from a C++ method.

The following code works in a unit test, but I believe that is only because the unit test is lucky and doesn't attempt to reuse the memory on the stack used by obj.

**Does this work?**

```
static MyObject createMyObject() {
    MyObject obj;
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: You can often answer this kind of question pretty easily by disassembling the output of the compiler, or setting it to emit an assembly file ( /FAcs in visual studio, -S in GCC, etc ). Just look at the actual code it produces.

Comment: It works, but it's no different from just declaring a `MyObject` at the destination directly (since you're simply returning a _copy_) -- i.e. `MyObject x = createMyObject();` achieves the same as the more efficient `MyObject x;`.

Comment: @Crashworks: That doesn't help distinguish between defined behaviour and luck...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : In this case it would directly answer "is the compiler returning a copy, or are we just using an old value in an expired stack frame?"

Comment: Just to be clear, the `static` keyword here is extraneous and possibly confusing.

Comment: On the other hand, `MyObject& createMyObject` would not work with this pattern, unless you use a static object as noted in one of the answers. `MyObject* createMyObject` would work if you returned a `new MyObject`.

Comment: Exactly what purpose do you think return values have if the above construct is not safe?

Comment: All you need is an object with an effed-up copy constructor to win your argument.  An array will proof your point.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What happens is that the copy constructor gets called to make a copy of the local object, and that is what the caller receives.

The compiler may eliminate the copy in a process called [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), but that's at the discretion of the compiler - you don't have much control over it.

This pattern is capable of producing the problems you're afraid of, but only if you're returning a *pointer* or *reference* to the local object.

Comment: "but only if the observable effects are the same." - no, the whole point of copy elision is that the copy can be eliminated even if the copy ctor has observable side-effects, such that the result is not the same. The implementation doesn't need a special rule to perform code transformations that *don't* alter observable effects, that can be done under the as-if rule.

Comment: Ok - this makes a lot more sense now. It sounds like this code is safe and will work and I don't have to fear segfaults.

Comment: Hi, if I am creating a local object inside the function through `MyClass *obj = new MyClass();`, returning the object pointer, and the signature of the method is `MyClass * myMethod(){...}`, if I call it like `MyClass *retObj = myMethod();`, and then dereference it like `retObject->someMethod();`, it is always working. Is it supposed to, or am I riding on luck?

Comment: @Cupidvogel that's a completely different situation from the question. Since you've used `new` to create and return a pointer, the object doesn't get copied but continues to exist until you `delete` the pointer. Where you run into problems is when you return a pointer to a *local* object, not one created with `new`.

Comment: I see. Is this because using `new` creates the object on the heap, that continues to persist irrespective of which function gets called and exited out of, whereas not using it creates it on stack which is local to the function, and thus offers no guarantee of existing once the function exits?

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. And I had to double check your display pic to ensure it is not Steve Jobs. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

`obj` is created, and then it is copied out of the method/function using the object's copy constructor.

You can make this `obj` to not to be in the stack by declaring it `static` too. Returning the object returns a copy too, but the object doesn't get created each time the function is called. Then, you can return the object as reference:

```
static MyObject & createMyObject() {
    static MyObject obj;
    return obj;
}
```

(no copy here, and also `obj` is created only once, and its address remains constant at runtime).

Comment: Although you need to be careful of static objects in a number of cases, such as in multithreaded code or when the destructor lives in a different shared library.

Answer (score 1):

You return the object by value, so it's copy constructor will be called, and a COPY of the original object will be returned and stored on the caller's stack. Should this method return a pointer (or reference) of a local variable it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

A **copy** of MyObject is returned. Which should be fine if MyObject has a copy constructor that copies everything correctly. Note it may have a copy constructor even without explicitly listing one -- The compiler defined default copy constructor (which assigns everything memberwise) may work fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, MyObject is being returned by value. That means that a copy of it is made and passed back to the calling function. (In certain cases [the compiler can optimize the spurious copy away](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), but only when that would be equivalent to calling the copy constructor on MyObject and placing the copy on the stack.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everyone else simply missed an obvious source of confusion in this question -- `static`:

You're not declaring the `MyObject` instance created in and returned from `createMyObject` as having static storage duration; rather, you're declaring the function `createMyObject` as having internal linkage.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok for a function to "return a local object", because the compiler will transform the function to *not* really return a value. Instead, it will accept a reference `MyObject& __result`, and use the local object which will be assigned the return value, i.e. `obj`, to copy construct the `__result`. In your case, the function will be rewritten to:

```
static void createMyObject(MyObject& __result) {
    MyObject obj;

    // .. process obj
    // compiler generated invocation of copy constructor
    __result.MyObject::Myobject( obj );

    return;
}
```

and every invocation of `createMyObject` will also be transformed to bind the reference to an existing object. For example, an invocation of the form:

```
MyObject a = createMyObject();
```

will be transformed to:

```
MyObject a;  // no default constructor called here
createMyObject(a);
```

However, if you return a reference or pointer to a local object, the compiler cannot fulfill the transform. You will be returning a reference or pointer to a already-destroyed object.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine. It will create a temporary anonymous variable that returns MyObject:

[Anonymous variables and objects](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/814-anonymous-variables-and-objects/)

[binding a temporary object to a reference to const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)